# Posting data into SQL Server 2012 database in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having trouble adding data to a SQL Server database. I have tried different combinations in my controller but nothing is working. I did see someone using lambada expression but I don't understand these and lost the link

Controller: Not sure what to do next

```
    public ActionResult Workout()
    {

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Workout(WorkoutModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            WorkoutModel workout = new WorkoutModel();

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "error");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Model :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace SportsCoach.Models
{
  public class UsersContext : DbContext
  {
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
  }

  [Table("UserProfile")]
  public class UserProfile
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
  }

[Table("WorkoutTable")]
public class WorkoutModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WorkoutDetails { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model SportsCoach.Models.WorkoutModel

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Workout";
   ViewBag.PageName = "Workout";
}

<section id="MainContent" class="container">
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Workouts</legend>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WorkoutDetails)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkoutDetails, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WorkoutDetails)
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
 }
</section>
```

Comment: Can you share your error message, what is it exactly.? Are you using model first approach.?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? An empty controller isn't going to help anyone diagnose the problem.

Comment: You are not giving controller and action name in the @Html.BeginForm() method, where the form will hit.?

Comment: @Ish it will use the current url by default.

Comment: one second i will update

Comment: also I am not getting no error now. it was just a useless using statement I am no longer using.